# Is there an R equivalent for the SPSS custom Tables feature?

Tags: r, spss, tables

I have used the custom tables feature in SPSS for my job almost every day. I am trying to learn R. How can I recreate the custom tables functionality in R? Is there some specific package that I need to use?

Comment: It would really help if you were to describe what the "custom tables feature" in SPSS actually does... As it stands now, this question can't be answered unless we know by heart what the custom tables feature of SPSS does. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Do you mean specifically 1) CTABLES command for producing tables, 2) Dialog menu for that command ("Custom Tables"), 3) Pivot table object in the output?

Comment: Yes,ttnphns I meant the dialog menu for that command Custom Tables.

Comment: Patrick custom table is a like a advanced Excel pivot table you can slide the table in many ways to create customer profile etc

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about looking for R packages.

Answer (score 5):

R has better capabilities than both PROC TABULATE and Custom tables in SPSS. PROC TABULATE drops observations with missing data on factor variables (which is why one must create dummy variables for the levels of those), and thats just for starters,

I'd recommend you to learn a few packages and I'll illustrate one of them.

Recommended packages:

- **tableone** for tabulating characteristics according to groups. Does also tabulate regression results.
- **stargazer** for tabulating regression results
- **texreg** for tabulating regression results
- **sjPlot** package for graphical assessments.

EXAMPLE

```
# Import data
rhc <- read.csv("http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/rhc.csv")

# Install packages
install.packages("tableone")
library(tableone)
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr
# Choose variables to tabulate
vars   <- names(select(rhc, edu, aps1, meanbp1, hrt1, resp1, temp1,
                     card, neuro, meta, seps, trauma))
# Tell R which of the variables are factors
factor <- names(select(rhc, card, neuro, meta, seps, trauma))
# Create the table
table  <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars,
                            strata = "race", # the grouping factor goes here
                            factorVars=factor,
                            data = rhc)
# Results
table
> table
                     Stratified by race
                      black          other          white          p      test
  n                    920            355            4460                     
  edu (mean (sd))      10.63 (3.35)   12.05 (3.34)   11.87 (3.04)  <0.001     
  aps1 (mean (sd))     56.30 (20.92)  55.77 (21.10)  54.24 (19.64)  0.010     
  meanbp1 (mean (sd))  85.34 (42.59)  77.86 (36.25)  77.16 (37.04) <0.001     
  hrt1 (mean (sd))    115.61 (43.64) 118.15 (36.70) 114.85 (41.08)  0.329     
  resp1 (mean (sd))    28.68 (15.28)  28.66 (13.39)  27.93 (13.87)  0.245     
  temp1 (mean (sd))    37.46 (1.95)   37.68 (1.68)   37.65 (1.74)   0.012     
  card = Yes (%)         302 (32.8)      99 (27.9)    1530 (34.3)   0.040     
  neuro = Yes (%)        123 (13.4)      48 (13.5)     522 (11.7)   0.256     
  meta = Yes (%)          59 (6.4)       21 (5.9)      185 (4.1)    0.006     
  seps = Yes (%)         191 (20.8)      74 (20.8)     766 (17.2)   0.013     
  trauma = Yes (%)        10 (1.1)        5 (1.4)       37 (0.8)    0.444
```

Good luck

Comment: Do you know of a way to mix the output of CreateTableOne with stargazer to put it nicely in a latex report?

Answer (score 1):

Custom Tables is SPSS's functional equivalent of SAS's TABULATE procedure, which is in its essence a special purpose language for creating an accountant's spreadsheet from a SAS dataset.  It's a very useful idea in reporting.

One thing I find helpful in using *R* is to keep in mind that *R* is more an environment for doing Statistics than a language.  *R* does not distinguish between its procedural and non-procedural components in the same way that SPSS does.  All of the tools necessary to create *any* sort of table are present in base *R*, all the time.  Define your operations on the dataframe and use them to create (a) new dataframe(s).  Print the resulting dataframes when you are done, controlling the formatting as you desire.

Comment: Why do you say that "R is more an environment for doing Statistics than a language"? I think you have that backwards. It's really a programming language that is tailored to statistical uses.

Comment: Opinions are like noses, everyone is entitled to one.  $R$ is Turing-complete, so it is a programming language.  But it is different in its conception from traditional languages like FORTRAN or C.  FORTRAN (or COBOL or C or Java or ...) are conceived to create programs that interact with the user, *without the user needing to know the underlying mechanism*.  $R$, by contrast is pretty useless to a user who doesn't both understand Statistics *and* the *R* system.  Use the mental model that works for you.

Comment: I guess so? but the comparison seems strange in contrast with SPSS. It sounded like you were saying SPSS was more of a "language" than R...

Comment: No.  That was not my intended meaning at all.  In fact, in my view SPSS is *less* of a language than *R*, especially for a user who avoids the "syntax" mode.

Comment: R is *both* the programming language and statistical environment. You can program anything in R, e.g. [minesweeper game](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fun/index.html) (there is nothing statistical in minesweeper as far as I know). To do statistics with R you need to know underlying mechanisms, but to program minesweeper you need only to know R language. To analyze data using Python packages you also need statistics background but Python is a programming language, the same with statistical functions written in FORTRAN (and available in R packages...).

Answer (score 0):

Not that powerfull as Custom Tables, but the sjPlot-package can create very nice SPSS like output.
Check [this blog post](http://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/no-need-for-spss-beautiful-output-in-r-rstats/)